# Trying to use GPU of laptop for TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have an HP au111tx laptop with Nvidia 940mx graphics card.

Is it possible for me to use this graphics card exclusively for ML. I want to use the integrated graphics card for normal display. I can use Windows or Ubuntu.